# Delete Realm DB file during the app installation in Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I want to delete and re install the Realm DB file during the installation. What is the best time to delete it.
All the other functions are working fine.
But I want to delete it and reinstall it while app installation。

Comment: Maybe you're looking for migration? Not sure why you would delete and reinstall it.

Comment: without deleting and reinstall the app (still in development) would not delete the data of DB. So I need to delete the existing DB and reinstall the DB.

Comment: do one thing as you are saying still in development, when ever app opens in Appdelegate add a method to delete from local like realm.delete(Object) (pass your object to be deleted).So that you will not have old data in that

Comment: while opening app and delete data cannot be done. it should be done in installation only

Comment: While opening app you can certainly delete data, the file or perform any other functions. The problem is we don't have enough information to direct you. Are you using MongoDB Realm? Is it sync'd to the server? Do you mean delete the data *within the realm* or delete the *actual realm file from the device*. What does *reinstall it* mean? Are you using a bundled realm? Please update and clarify the question and we'll take a look.